# Turn off thumbnails for desktop icons

Tags: icons, customization, desktop-icons

How do you turn off the thumbnails for desktop icons?

EDIT following Oli's answer: Is it possible to do this for the desktop icons without affecting the normal behaviour of the nautilus file manager?

Comment: Do you want to turn off thumbnails on just the desktop, or in folder windows (e.g. Places -> Home Folder) as well?

Comment: Normally I use "List View" for most folders - but I'd like to be able to choose to have previews/thumbnails in some folders.  I don't think that Oli's solution lets me do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open up a directory in nautilus (via places, etc)
2. Click the edit menu, Preferences, Preview tab
3. For the first two fields (text and other), select Never.

Comment: Doesn't that turn off previews for all files, not just those on the desktop?